# AddEventListener: onmousedown

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, dom-events, mousedown

I am creating a Chrome Extension which checks to see if there is "onmousedown" attribute and if so I will execute some code.

I have tried this however it isn't working.

```
document.addEventListener("onmousedown", function() {

});
```

Comment: What does it have to do with jQuery? This is precisely NOT jQuery

Comment: Sorry, I meant Javascript.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It is `mousedown` not `onmousedown`.

```
object.addEventListener("mousedown", myScript);
```

ref: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmousedown.asp